# No aparece mi imagen en mi index local pero en el liver server si

Tags: html, css

Inserte una imagen de fondo en un div usando la URL de la imagen, cuando activo el live server aparece de forma correcta, pero cuando abro la web desde mi archivo local HTML me indica el siguiente error:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Comment: Podrias especificar el path de la imagen como la tenés definida?...como dijo Einstein todo es relativo

Comment: background-image: url(/paginas/Imagenes/Swap/Fondo-cuadro4.jpg);

Comment: Inserte la imagen como fondo en un div solo utilizando css

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx. Las respuestas a los comentarios se dan yendo a [edit] la pregunta y añadiendo allá la info correspondiente.

Comment: Pueden ser varias cosas: 
Fijate donde tenes ubicado el css, en caso de estar definido en un archivo aparte la imagen es relativa a este archivo respecto a la carpeta de la imagen

Comment: Al parecer no deja insertar ninguna imagen en el div, en los demás divs si las inserta sin ningún problema pero en el div que deseo insertarla no deja a ninguna imagen